# Minimize repeating code for forms in application

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application which uses a lot of forms. I use bootstrap formfields like this:

```
        <form id="NewComp">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="NameInput">Naam</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NameInput" placeholder="Example input">
                    </div>   
                </td>
                <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="FullNameInput">Volledige naam </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FullNameInput" placeholder="Example input">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

These forms can be huge so I would like to simplify things using an include or .js (external function) to keep my mainpage cleaner.

For example:

```
<form id="NewComp">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="myTextField" parameters"label=Naam, id=NameInput"></div>
                </td>
             </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
```

When I understand the basics how to achieve something like this, I can adjust it for my code en even eliminate some  code.

Can someone point me in te right direction?

Comment: Which is your backend language? or is it just static HTML project?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad for SO imho. There is really plenty of solutions, and the best for you depend on so many things, it's hard for us to help you from here

Comment: Data is filled bij Javscript (jquery). But mainly static html.

Comment: I hope there are a lot of solutions but for the moment I do not have any direction (with my basic knowledge... sorry). Some suggestions might help me a lot. I do not ask for a complete code example...

Comment: Well, that's the point. This platform is mainly meant to answer code questions, including code samples, and requiring code answers. I'll try to give it a shot, but I really think you should better go for your own searches about webdev tutorials on google

Comment: @Logar, thanks a lot. Of course, I tried google but could not figure out a good search query for my question an, more or less, got lost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I will try to give you some suggestions, this is too long for a comment but cannot really be considered as an answer..

First of all, if you want a basic website and you are not/don't want to be a web developer, just leave your code as it is now, it's totally fine.

If however you want to learn code or are trying to build a large and scalable application, there is a few things you can try to learn (here are some examples but you can just find plenty of great web development tutorials out there) :

- If you want to get rid of bootstrap classes (which are fine, really), you can include your own css pages.
- If you want to dynamically render html, you can look into html templates and stay with basic jquery, and unless you want to handle templating by hand, you will have to include a javascript lib that handles them, for example underscore.js. This might be the more suitable solution for you if you just want a quick solution that reduces the amount of code.
- If you want to build a larger app, you might want to learn some js framework as reactjs, vuejs, or angular (there are plenty of them out there, but these 3 are the most popular by now). But the learning curve of one of these tools will be a bit long if you are new to javascript and programming.

I hope this helps

Comment: You should suggest angular instead of angularjs. angularjs is outdated

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'm not really following angular atm. Answer updated

Comment: Thanks a lot. This gives me some direction!